# Global exception handler bubbled from DOM events

Tags: angular, exception, dom-events

Angular 2 provides a way to be notified about an unhandled exception by implementing a custom global [`ErrorHandler`](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler).

However, by doing that we still can't recover an app from getting unresponsive and usually a user will have to reload the page.

The two most common places for exception handling in Angular 2 I could think of are `Observable`s and DOM event handlers. Let's put the former place aside for this question and focus on the latter one.

So, to overcome the unresponsive app behavior in some way, I'd like to have a global handler of unhandled exceptions bubbling from DOM events. This way we could catch, handle and swallow them before they break something inside Angular. My current idea of how we could implement it is as follows.

All DOM events run inside a `NgZone` and browser native JavaScript classes are monkey-patched by `zone.js`. So, is there an extension point provided by `zone.js` we could plug into to attach our handler for unhandled exceptions happened inside a DOM event handler?

Or if someone has a better idea as to how we can handle unhandled exceptions bubbled from inside a DOM event handler, I'd appreciate your thoughts!